# Report filter parameter

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

I'm trying to add a filter parameter in a report in Visual Studio 2013 like this tutorial

[Reporting Service Tutorial - Basic Parameters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9bOO109bY8&index=11&list=PL7A29088C98E92D5F)

but in VS2013, when I click on add parameter, I can't find the option to prompt the parameter to the user, like in youtube video I linked.

[Add Parameter Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwOjq.jpg)

Someone can help me please?

Comment: There's not really enough detail here to expect a helpful answer to your specific issue.  Can you include a screenshot of your report so far?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give a little bot more detail? In the screen shot your in the parameter properties window which is the correct location to configure a parameter for a report. If you want to see it as if a user was interacting with it you need to click on the preview tab.